# Excel without VBA: How to create a sequential number following pattern from a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following table:

[image]

I'd like to fill automatically the column with '001,002...' following the previous column. Please see the image to see the pattern (We'll have many in the future, it's crazy doing it manually)

I'm attching an example file: https://1drv.ms/x/s!Akmhm4db64ebrHQF9rlhwNUa7tdS?e=kUkFlV

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `TEXT` and `IF`, like the following:

```
=TEXT(IF(A2<>A1,1,B1+1),"000")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tested this formula in excel and it worked for me.  Paste into cell B2 for your L4 code column and just copy down.  As new items are added in column A, the pattern will repeat.

```
=IF(A2=A1,BASE(B1+1,10,3),BASE(1,10,3))
```

If you need to have it automatically populate to a predetermined row, drag the formula down (for example 1,000 rows) and use the following:

```
=IF(A2="","",IF(A2=A1,BASE(B1+1,10,3),BASE(1,10,3)))
```

Just for explanation purposes, what the formula is doing is looking at the previous item in column A and checking to see if it is the same as the current item, if yes, increment by 1, else start over at 1. The BASE function is adding the leading 0's.